# MacOSX: Writing a Dock plugin under 10.8.x using [Easy]SIMBL?

Tags: macos, plugins, dock, simbl

I'm trying to write a Dock plugin under MacOSX 10.8.2 using EasySIMBL, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I followed the instructions in Section 7.2 here: http://culater.net/wiki/moin.cgi/CocoaReverseEngineering

I tried both "com.apple.dock" and "com.apple.Dock" as my bundle identifiers, but the "load" method of my plugin is still never getting invoked.

Has anyone ever gotten a plugin to work with the Dock using SIMBL (or EasySIMBL in Lion/Mountain Lion)? If so, could you point me to some sample code that I could use as a starting point? ... or could you direct me to some Dock-specific instructions for writing SIMBL-based plugins?